# MySQL insert but update/ignore duplicate

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates

This is my table with some sample data

```
C ID | D ID    | Details |
--------------------------
 a   | b_data1 | d1      |
 a   | b_data2 | d2      |
 b   | b_data1 | d1      |
 b   | b_data2 | d2      |
 c   | b_data1 | d1      |
 c   | b_data2 | d2      |
```

When I run this query##

`INSERT IGNORE INTO table_name (C_ID, D_ID, Details) VALUES ('C', 'b_data3','d3') ('C', 'b_data2','d2')`

It inserts both those rows when it's supposed to ignore the second value pair `('C', 'b_data2','d2')`

No indexes /primary key are defined.

I want to make sure there is no duplicate row, means data in three columns combined should make the row unique. I can't make it unique .As I have illustrated here, a can keep same content as b but a should not have a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL enforces unique constraints with UNIQUE indexes. If you wish to add the index without recreating the table, you would do:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name ON table (C_ID, D_ID, Details)
```

In addition to INSERT IGNORE and the already mentioned REPLACE, you can also use INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE for more control over what happens when insert runs into a duplicate unique.

Comment: but i cant make it unique. i have illustrated there . a can keep same content as b but a should not have a duplicate

Comment: I'm afraid, MySql requires primary key or uniqe index to keep duplicates away.

Comment: Thanks alot for ur helps .. 
I'm clear now on its usage .. i cant create unique/primary key . i had to query and do !in_array($data, $query_array) to over come this

Answer (score 2):

`INSERT IGNORE` means "ignore rows that break unique constraints, instead of failing the query". You need to define `UNIQUE` columns for it to work as you expect it to — e.g. `CREATE TABLE tablename (col1 type, col2 type, col3 type, UNIQUE (col1, col2, col3))`

Comment: I cant make it unique as this is a collection page,
E.g  should be able to store `a > b_data1 > d1 and a > b_data2 >  d2 ` and  b `b > b_data1 > d1 and b > b_data2 >  d2 ` 
table about i illustrated. a can have same content of collection b but cant have same in a

Comment: If you define `UNIQUE (col1, col2, col3)`, this means you cannot have the same values in ALL of these columns. I.e., you can have the same value in `col1` as long as either `col2` or `col3` is different. Or you can have the same value in `col2` and `col3` as long as `col1` is different. It is a compound index on all three columns, does not mean that each of them needs to be unique.

Comment: Thanks alot for ur helps .. 
I'm clear now on its usage .. i cant create unique/primary key in this table as there is no unique single colum. its unique when all 3 combined. i had to query and do !in_array($data, $query_array) to over come this

Answer (score 0):

You should define composed uniqe index as @lanzz suggested. If you want new records to replace the old ones in the case of index clash, use [replace](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) statement.

Comment: but i cant make it unique. i have illustrated there . a can keep same content as b but a should not have a duplicate