# to ignore duplicates and insert new record in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table name course. It has following data in it:

```
mca
bca
msc
me
```

Now when I enter 2 values at a time mca mtech. It should accept mtech and ignore mca. Please anyone help to solve.

```
Field   Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Action
    id  int(15)         No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT   Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index  Fulltext
    register_number varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None         Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index  Fulltext
    name    varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None         Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index  Fulltext
    course_code varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None         Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index  Fulltext
    subject_code    varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None         Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index  Fulltext
    exam_name   varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None         Browse distinct values  Change  Drop    Primary     Unique  Index  Fulltext
```

Comment: would u mind sharing your table structure please and also ur desired output as it is not clear from your question.

Comment: if there is an unique key on the column you can use `INSERT IGNORE INTO...`

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL insert but update/ignore duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775471/mysql-insert-but-update-ignore-duplicate)

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1(column1, column2, ... 
VALUES value_for_column1, value_for_column2, ...
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE column1 = value_for_column1)
```